# Core data how to create child context and "switch" context

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

Hello I’m starting on iOS swift dev. I want to manipulate NSManagedObjects « freely » without take the risk of « storing » objects that I dont want to save. I’ve read that creating NSManaged object without context is bad so here is my question.
How I can create « child » contexts and how can I switch from my « pending context » to my «  to save context » ? I find this behavior really weird of the core data and "dangerous »…